# UITableView With Multiple Sections

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I want to make tableView with multiple section but i do  not want to use dictionary i have two arrays i want that first array should be loaded in first section and second in second sections.

I have arrayOne with 3 items and arrayTwo with 4 items so how to add them and show them in sections.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(section == 0)
        return resultArray.count;
    else
        return resultArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Number of Sections");
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Section 1";
    if(section == 1)
        return @"Section 2";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSLog(@"Table Cell Data");
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

     appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     if (indexPath.section==0) {    
         appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
         ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
         NSLog(@"Cell Values %@",cellValue);
         cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
         return cell;
     }
     else {
         ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
         cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
         return cell;       
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Your code seem correct.

Comment: assignig value in cell gives section error section not declared

Comment: You have to use indexPath.section and not just section in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Now what values you are getting in console.? and one more thing you should not create this object appDelegate in this function. This will increase memory issues only. Not a good practise.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return 2 ;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if (section==0)
      {
             return [array1 count];
      }
      else{
             return [array2 count];
      }
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if(section == 0)
           return @"Section 1";
      else
           return @"Section 2";
 }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

 if (indexPath.section==0) {
     ObjectData *theCellData = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
     cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
 }
 else {
     ObjectData *theCellData = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
     cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
 }
     return cell;        
 }
```

Comment: This - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if (indexPath.section==0)
      {
             return [array1 count];
      }
      else{
             return [array1 count];
      }
 } is wrong. You can't get indexPath.section here.

Comment: Can you NSLog you cellValue and see if there is some data in it or not

Comment: it is not showing NSLog of anything in where we wrute the method for cellForRowAtIndex except that in sections and number of rows NSLog is working so it means it is not entering in rowForIndexPath

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25333/discussion-between-shashank-kulshrestha-and-nazia-jan)

Comment: Good answer...you just need to change the else statement to return the  count of array2 not array1.

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha my current section highlight till second section appear.is this by default ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant Swift 3 lines:

```
func numberOfSections (in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    ...
    return numberOfSections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    //Not necessary, but will let you format the section headers. Example:
    guard let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView else { return }
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    header.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    header.textLabel?.frame = header.frame
    view.tintColor = UIColor.white
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    //Also not necessary, but clear footers help space out sections
    view.tintColor = UIColor.clear   
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //Spacing between sections:
    return 25
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    ...
    return sectionCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //All your cell setup
    ...
    //I call this to get the absolute row number (disregarding sections)
    let row = getAbsoluteRow_InCurrentSection(indexPath: indexPath)
    //Now you can use the row number to grab a value from an array or CoreData object and use the value to populate your cell!! 
}

func getAbsoluteRow_InCurrentSection(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    var aggRows = 0
    if currentListEntity == "GrocTask" {
        let curSection = indexPath.section
        for i in 0..<curSection {
            aggRows += flex1ArrayCnt[i]
        }
        aggRows += indexPath.row
    }
    return aggRows
}
```

//Please be aware, I only included those directly relevant to building a UITableView with sections. I did not include editActions, didSelect, or other UITableView delegate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `if (section==0)`

to `if (indexPath.section==0)`

You have to implement this function :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 {
     if(section == 0)
         return arrSection1.count;
      else
         return arrSection2.count;
 }
```

Comment: again it is giving error i have done like this indexPath.section

Comment: @NaziaJan did u implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` should be something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return firstArray.count;
    } else {
        return secondArray.count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on almost right track....

Let us consider your two arrays are `arrOne` and `arrTwo`.....

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if(section == 0)
      return [arrOne count];
      else
      return [arrTwo count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
        {

         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          }

             if (indexPath.section==0) {


        ObjectData *theCellData = [arrOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
        NSLog(@"cellValue = %@",cellValue); //To see the value of string cellValue
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

        return cell;

    }

    else {
        ObjectData *theCellData = [arrTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

        return cell;        
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess P should be capital in indexpath,.... have edited that. Now try, it should work.

Comment: i have added one line of code, add that in your code and see if you are getting correct value in your string to print in your cell label. Try that once.

Answer (score 0):

**TableView Delegate Method already give the section as *:(NSInteger)section*.. so we can also use switchCase**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0:
                return self.arrMedia.count;
                break;
            case 1:
                return 1;
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```