# How to make cell doesn't scroll along with other cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I am making an app that use table View Controller and static cell.
I want to make first cell don't scrolling while other can. This is a picture of what i am talking about.(Sorry for my bad English)

[image]

For example as in this picture, I want to make 9gag tab stay when scroll. If you play instragram you will see that when you scrolling the name of user will stay until you scroll into another one. However I want it to stay not changing when it encounter second cell.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Make the first "cell" part of the section header.

Answer (score 1):

Using `UITableViewController` would not help here. You can use these steps to get what you want:
1. Create a UIViewController.
2. Add UITableView as its subview.
3. Add another UIView as UIViewController's view's subview.
4. Using auto layout constraints, you can put UIView above UITableView

This way, you will get a sticky view at the top.

Comment: If i do this way I cannot use static cell. I want to use static cell to design my app. Is this only way? @Udit Agarwal

Comment: You can create the static view in a xib and then use it as the subview of both UIView on top and as the subview of the cells in UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not exactly sure what you're after but i'll take a stab.

Firstly, if you want the section to remain in place until a new section of items is present, you just need have a look at sections.  This is an automatic feature. You may not see it occur until you have plenty of items in the sections.

[UITableView With Multiple Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151037/uitableview-with-multiple-sections)

There's plenty of stuff about it & not too hard to implement.

My other guess of what you want:

If you want it to remain static regardless of anything, perhaps you could just create a view and place it above the table view. why does it need to be a part of it if it doesn't change?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear. I want a sticky view as in instragram but i do it in  table view controller. Is there any way to make cell become sticky view on the top? @Ben